# Problems with PHP, preg_replace & regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to run this php command:

```
preg_replace($regexp, $replace, $text, $maxsingle);
```

Where the vars are:

```
$regexp = '/(?!(?:[^<\\[]+[>\\]]|[^>\\]]+<\\/a>))\\b(שלום)\\b/imsU';
$replace = '<a title="$1" href="http://stackoverflow.com">$1</a>';
$text is a long post
$maxsingle = 3;
```

When the text I'm trying to match (in the above case "שלום") is in english everything works. However, when the text is Hebrew, it doesn't matches anything...

Any ideas how to make Hebrew work with `preg_replace`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the /u (utf-8) flag

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. where should i put it? Can you please paste me the exact regexp? thanks.

Comment: $regexp = '/(?!(?:[^<\\\[]+[>\\\]]|[^>\\\]]+<\\/a>))\\b(שלום)\\b/imsuU';