# Regular expression find word Hebrew

Tags: php, hebrew

I'm looking for a pattern to find exactly word Hebrew on Article content.

Example:

$word = 'דף הבית';

please help me!

Comment: something wrong with preg_match() ??

Comment: Please clarify: you want to find the word "Hebrew", find the word "Hebrew" IN Hebrew, or find a Hebrew word??

Comment: word write by Hebrew language

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$subject = "STRING_TO_SEARCH";
$pattern = '/^דף הבית$/';
preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php  for more examples on the php function.

If you want to find any word written in Hebrew, change the $pattern to 
    /^[first letter|second letter|...]/ 
for each letter of the Hebrew alphabet. This is essentially, if the word begins with the first letter or the second letter and so on.

Comment: Thank! I have Content Article:

Example:

$content ='אבן גיר רכה, שהינה בדרך כלל תוצר של עבודות חציבה בצפון הארץ ובשומרון. האבן מסופקת בצורת גושים בגודל ראש, ומשמשת בעיקר לבניית גדרות וקירות תומכים. אבן כורכר - אבן חול צהובה, שמוצאה מאזור משור החוף. ממנה בנויים מבנים רבים ביפו העתיקה. כיום היא נחצבת בעיקר בסביבת הכפר ג'סר א-זרקא. אבן נקב - אבן גיר קשה בצבע צהוב אפור, הנחצבת באזור באר שבע. '

$word = 'הנחצבת באזור';

$pattern = ?

Comment: So you want to find the value of $word in $content?

Comment: yes, sorry my english is bad. My question similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173527/problems-with-php-preg-replace-regular-expressions

Comment: So then for $pattern should be '/^הנחצבת באזור$/'

Comment: The ^ means that your pattern starts with the first value ר and the $ means that the pattern ends with the last character ה.